# How to Create database through java using google app engine?

Tags: mysql, database, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

Since i am new to Google app engine, i need to create database and table through java code. Can anyone help to create the database, i am trying to figured it out to create connection but i am getting an exception

Here's my basic connection code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/irescue?user=root";
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
             Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
             String sql = "CREATE TABLE REGISTRATION " +
                       "(id INTEGER not NULL, " +
                       " first VARCHAR(255), " + 
                       " last VARCHAR(255), " + 
                       " age INTEGER, " + 
                       " PRIMARY KEY ( id ))"; 
              Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
              stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

but i am getting an exception like this

```
org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugException: com.sun.jdi.ClassNotLoadedException: Type has not been loaded occurred while retrieving component type of array.
```

Can anyone help me to know the database creation using google app engine.

Answer (score 0):

AppEngine does not support MySql database. It provides the Datastore which is a NoSql database. The datastore scales way better than traditional relational databases but to do so it introduces trade-off on some properties (like consistency). If you really need a relational DB you can use CloudSQL which is a MySql server running on the Google Cloud infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

There are few steps that are needed to be done for an AppEngine application to use CloudSQL. You should be able to find details [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/).